# Redirecting PHP to Multiple Redirects using Query Strings

Tags: string

I just completed building a website for a client, he utilized an external form plugin. Now this particular form has a drop down for 8 products and sends Query Strings **(Url.com?Product+1, URL.com?Product+2 etc.)** once either product is selected and the form is submitted. Now utilizing this Query string, we need to redirect the client to 8 different external websites.

So for instance - a customer walks in and selects "Product 1" from the drop down he needs to be redirected to www.product1.com, if he selects "Product 2" he needs to go to www.product2.com

I can enable the Query string to go to a PHP file rather than the main URL - so if or she select "Product 6" in the drop down - I can have him sent to URL.com/redirect.php?Product+6

But then I want this to redirect to Product6.com - how do I achieve this?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1):

do it like this redirect him to URL.com/redirect.php?url=Product6

now,

```
//redirect.php
if(isset($_GET["url"])){
    $uri = $_GET["url"];
    if ($uri == "product1"){
        header( 'Location: http://www.somewebsite.com') ;
    }
    if ($uri == "product2"){
        header( 'Location: http://www.differentwebsite.com') ;
    }
}
else{
    echo "No target URL provided" 
}
```

URL.com/redirect.php?uri=product1 will go to somewebsite.com URL.com/redirect.php?uri=product+name will go to differentwebsite.com

Comment: Sarvesh,

Thanks for the reply - the problem is the products donot have a static domain at all. As in not every product has a productname.com registered.

So "product 1" may redirect to http://www.product1.com and "product 8" will be sent to "http://www.websitename.com/somethinghere"

Comment: "But then I want this to redirect to Product6.com - how do I achieve this?" I thought you were trying to redirect them to productX.com

Comment: Yes, that was an error on my part! I am kind of bumped about this!

So how do I do it now?

Comment: So now where do you want to redirect your user?

Comment: For every query string - I want to be able to redirect them to a different link!

So URL.com/redirect.php?Product+1 should go to http://www.somewebsite.com

URL.com/redirect.php?Product+Name should go to http://www.differentwebsite.com/somepage.html

etc.

Comment: I am getting! 

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ISSET, expecting '(' in /home/blogpolice/public_html/direct/redirect.php on line 3

Comment: change it to if(isset($_GET["url"])){

Comment: how can it be that it is still expectimg '(' ?

Comment: make it redirect to -> clientsite.com/folder/redirect.php?url=Product+Name

Comment: Well, Sorry but do you understand php even one bit? (You need to put some effort from your side too, no one has time to waste trying to tell you everything when you are not even bothering to read the code.) In php code you have two if blocks for cases of url==product1 and url==product2. As you are not printing or doing anything for case of url=="ProductName" so it is obvious that it will show blanck page. You have to  make all 8 if blocks for case of url=="productX" where X is from 1 to 8.

Comment: OMG... so just commenting on your zero effort made you so angry, even after going through the trouble adding a "Sorry" before saying anything ( As it was meant to be a comment+advise for future, but your reply says all about narrow-mindedness of yourself). In case you didn't notice that no one else bothered to answer you question -> let me tell you that Your question is not written well enough to be answered by anyone on StackOverFlow -> But I did because I was interested in helping a new programmer. Well now I realize that people like you don't deserve a community like StackOverFlow.